# Generating static objects in xtext

Tags: code-generation, xtext, xtend

continue to the example of generating a field such as:

```
def handle (EClass c) {
  val attr = EcoreFactory::eINSTANCE.createEAttribute
  attr.name = "test"
  attr.EType = EcorePackage::eINSTANCE.EString
  c.EStructuralFeatures += attr
}
```

can I generate it as a static field? how to do so?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Please formulate your questions more clearly to get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ecore differs from Java's object model, and unfortunately, EAttributes can't be static like fields in Java can.